# How do we feel about questions that are basically quizzes?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

Recently there have been some questions which seem to have been posted intended as quizzes for users here rather than as legitimate questions. This isn't something I can prove, but given the nature and timing of the questions it seems like the answers were actually known to the OP at the time. Moreover, the questions were of the type that were probably not interesting to anyone else, e.g. identification style questions or extremely trivial facts.

I know that it's fine to ask questions that you already know the answer to, though in such cases it's usually good to write your own answer. However, is it still encouraged if the question is not likely to be interesting or useful to anyone else? Put another way, is it appropriate to downvote and/or vote to close questions where the OP clearly already knows the answer and is only posting to test us? It seems to me that all that kind of question does is inflate rep scores and fill our site with random questions that aren't really interesting to anyone.

As a note, even if it is acceptable to take negative actions against such posts, it should probably only be done once one is certain that the question fits this description.

Comment: Well, if they become a real problem latter like: "Hey, I'm in the 3rd season but I don't recognize this guy" the guy **being the darn MC!!** is to vote down those users until they actually give some trough before asking those kind of... questions? Unless there is some kind of plot behind why one could not recognize him.

Comment: Do you have any specific examples?

Comment: @kuwaly The ones that led me to consider this are http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/ and http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/, but I'm not actually sure whether those fall in this category. I'm more looking to see if there's a general consensus that such questions should/shouldn't be allowed, rather than trying to bring down those specific potential examples.

Comment: Trivial questions usually fall into the not enough research was made into them, so yeah, you can downvote in my opinion. I'll give a better answer when I'm next to a PC.

Comment: For what it's worth, Scifi doesn't seem too fond of this sort of question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40813/what-place-is-harry-ginny-right-now-in-this-setting#comment77546_40813

Comment: another sample would be http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5254/who-is-this-anime-girl-character/5279#5279 before it got edited. were it is obvious the person knows this already